# how to fetch count of emails in a specific month in Gmail API

Tags: php, email, gmail, gmail-api

i'm using Gmail API to fetch user emails and showing number of emails within a month on graph. but looping through each email to count emails is not efficient. is there any other way i can fetch that count? for example how many emails are sent or received in September?

Of course, we can use after: or before: filters, but if i have to fetch counts of whole year then it would take 12 API calls. if there any other way i can fetch count in 1 call? or any other efficient method? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think your only option is to list messages with a query `after:<start_date> before:<end_date>` until there is no `nextPageToken` in the response, and then take the total count:

```
function getMessageCount($service, $userId, $query) {
  $pageToken = NULL;
  $messages = array();
  $opt_param = array(
    'q' => $query
  );
  do {
    try {
      if ($pageToken) {
        $opt_param['pageToken'] = $pageToken;
      }
      $messagesResponse = $service->users_messages->listUsersMessages($userId, $opt_param);
      if ($messagesResponse->getMessages()) {
        $messages = array_merge($messages, $messagesResponse->getMessages());
        $pageToken = $messagesResponse->getNextPageToken();
      }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      print 'An error occurred: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
  } while ($pageToken);

  return count($messages);
}
```

If you would like to get the amount of messages between e.g. `Friday, September 1, 2017 12:00:00 AM` and `Sunday, October 1, 2017 12:00:00 AM`, you would then call it like this:

```
$count = getMessageCount($service, 'me', 'after:1504224000 before:1506816000');
```